# What underlying items should be included when reviewing a server for Application Minimum requirements?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Windows 2012 server needs to be evaluated for minimum requirements for a new application. Although the server seems that it can have the software installed onto it, I still want to be able to see the full picture so I'm not surprised a month down the road. Which additional items should I be checking besides the spec-sheet?

Thank you

### App Requirements

- CPU: 2HZ (x86, or x64)
- RAM 2GB
- 30GB of Hard Drive space
- Gig Ethernet

### Server Resources

- CPU: Intel Xeon E5649 @ 2.53GHz
- RAM: 8GB
- HDD: 80GB Free
- Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also consider the remaining support lifetime of the hardware and OS you intend to use.

For instance, Windows Server 2012 mainstream support has ended, and extended lifecycle support will end in 2023. So this OS will get only the most critical security updates, may not receive any future bug fixes, and will not receive any new features. You may need to use a newer OS. Some applications just shouldn't be deployed on an old OS at all, such as many web applications.

The hardware also dates back to 2011, and it's probably already out of warranty. Consider the cost of the extended support contract you will need plus the power consumption of such old hardware, versus the cost of new and much more capable hardware, or more likely a virtual machine taking up only a small slice of some modern hardware.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought about the actual hardware this is running on, or warranties. Should I also worry about the applications installed and features enabled on the server?